# How to set Antd icon as a ::before pseudo selector of a button?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

Currently, I'm passing Icons as a prop to the button component

```
<div className="offer-actions">
          <Button type="link" icon={<EyeOutlined />}>
            View
          </Button>
          {offer.pause ? (
            <Button type="link" icon={<PlayCircleOutlined />}>
              Resume
            </Button>
          ) : (
            <Button type="link" icon={<PauseCircleOutlined />}>
              Pause
            </Button>
          )}
          <Button type="link" icon={<EditOutlined />}>
            Edit
          </Button>
</div>
```

And it's rendering like this on the page

[image]

I would like to have the icons appear to the left of the button text

[image]

I tried adding a CSS pseudo selector :before but not sure what to add to content

```
:before
{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the text alignment on the Button

```
<Button type="link" className="my-custom-button" icon={<EyeOutlined />}>
  View
</Button>
```

```css
.my-custom-button {
  text-align: left
}
```

Comment: Nice, that worked. Would still have liked to know the pseudo selector method as well.

Comment: I want the answer to the actual question, not a workaround.